# Team Foundation TF.exe Method not found

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one.  I'm trying to queue up a build which starts, but when it gets to running a tf.exe checkout /recursive, it returns the following error.  I've searched the internet, high and low but have been unable to figure out this issue.

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.TeamFoundationIdentity Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.get_AuthorizedIdentity()'.

Another message that comes up is

> C:\Builds\10\ProjectBuild\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (84): The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools..\IDE\tf.exe" checkout /recursive "C:\Builds\10\ProjectBuild\Sources\Code\ProjectBuild\ProjectBuild.vbproj"" exited with code 100.

I removed the Sources folder within the Build folder and rerun the build, which then returns this as part of the error as well now.

> Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 't
>   f workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you installed different versions of visual studio? Try using the full path of the tf.dxe instance that you wish to run, to be sure it's using the right one. Try the same command from your command line to confirm that it works.

Comment: The workspace in the build is going to be the sources folder and so that is why you get the last error after you remove the Sources folder.

Comment: How would I go about changing it if its pointing to the wrong TF.exe?

Comment: @MikeCheel That makes sense, but still getting the other error(s).  I believe its suppose to be using Visual Studio 11.0, but its using 10.0.  Do I update this in the server or within the project?

Comment: Find the tf.exe that is in the 11.0 folder and put THAT path in your build script \ process. Then try running your command and see how it goes. Once that is working, move it into your build script.

Comment: Are you using the correct build workflow template for your build?

Comment: AuthorizedIdentity is a property introduced in 2012, so the error is caused by using older assemblies.

Comment: @MikeCheel Your help was what got me going in the right direction.  If you post as answer, I'll accept it.  You were correct in that I was pointing to 10.0 versus 11.0 in the build script/process.  Made the changes needed and was able to get past this problem.  Then another problem came, but I was able to figure that one out on my own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the tf.exe that is in the 11.0 folder and put THAT path in your build script \ process. Then try running your command and see how it goes. Once that is working, move it into your build script.